# What is difference between select count(1) from table and select count(*) from table

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

What is difference between select count(1) from table ;
and select count(*) from table ;

Here my table contain 5rows and 5column

Comment: Surely this is a dupe?

Answer (score 4):

Nothing. `count(1)` is implicitly transformed into `count(*)`. See below:

```
SQL> select tracefile from v$process where addr = (select paddr from v$session where sid = sys_context('userenv', 'sid'));

TRACEFILE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/orcl_o71/ORCL/trace/ORCL_ora_3610.trc

SQL> alter session set events '10053 level 1';

Session altered.

SQL> select count(1) from dual;

  COUNT(1)
----------
         1

SQL> alter session set events '10053 off';

Session altered.

SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.4.0.0.0
[oracle@o71 ~]$ grep "Final query" -A 1 /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/orcl_o71/ORCL/trace/ORCL_ora_3610.trc
Final query after transformations:******* UNPARSED QUERY IS *******
SELECT COUNT(*) "COUNT(1)" FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "DUAL"
[oracle@o71 ~]$
```